# flutter application, Gradle Project Sync Failed, Build not found

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am running on Mac, and I have a flutter project, and I am trying to use Sync Project with Gradle files on Android Studio. But I get these errors:

Build not found: BuildId(buildRoot=/users/username/dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle)
available builds {BuildId(buildRoot=/Users/username/repo/notification-hub-demo2/pushdemo/android)=:, BuildId(buildRoot=/Users/username/dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle)=:gradle}

I have latest of everything, as I just installed all couple of days ago.

I tried to delete the .gradle folder, and run android studio again but I got same error.

Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the case difference between the two parts of the error: "buildRoot=/users/username" and "buildRoot=/Users/username". Is it possible that some environment variable is set to the lowercase version of the path (which happens to work on macOS due to the case-insensitive file system)?

Gradle seems to be finicky about requiring that builds have the exact correct canonical path, including case sensitivity.

Comment: Thaaaaanks... I had no idea that in MacOS paths are case sensitive!! everyday I hate Mac more :). If this will be helpful to anyone, fixing the path didn't fix the issue for me, but I looked through my settings file for where "flutter_tools" is used and ended up fixing it in ./android/settings.gradle changed includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle") to includeBuild("/users/akhudairy/dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle"). This worked. however proper should be to fix variable {settings.ext.flutterSdkPath} which currently i don't know how to